# Persistent timer on HTML page load

Tags: javascript, html, timer, onload, persistent

I have this persistent JavaScript timer. I want to start the timer on page load of an HTML page (and maybe end it on a specific page).

HTML:

```
<div>Time remaining: <span id="timer"></span></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var interval = 30000;

function reset()
{
    localStorage.endTime = +new Date + interval;
}

if(!localStorage.endTime)
{
    reset();
}

setInterval(function()
{
    var remaining = localStorage.endTime - new Date;
    if( remaining >= 0 )
    {
        $('#timer').text( Math.floor( remaining / 1000 ) );
    } else
    {
        reset();
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Is the issue how to call `reset()` when a particular page loads, but not a different one?

Comment: The timer should be persistent throughout multiple pages, but should be initially called on a specfic page and reset on that page aswell.

Comment: This seems like it should accomplish that, or something close, already. What happens differently when you test it? (Also: are you testing it as a website served from a web server, or opening the pages as local files in your browser – `file:///…`? For security reasons, local files don’t share state, so only a web server will let you test local storage.)

Comment: I am opening it in VS Code with a Live Server and the javascript file is shared with multiple html pages. So I don't know how to implement the reset() on for example my index.html page, without it being called on every page.

Comment: I would suggest adding a second JavaScript file that’s included on just the index.html page and calls `reset()` as the most straightforward way to get it working. (After that, you could try alternative approaches, like adding an attribute to some element – like `<html data-reset-timer="true">` – and checking for it in your single script.)